# Node.js is trolling me. Generating random names and tweets using arrays

Tags: javascript, arrays, random

This question involves a snippet of code which is supposed to generate random tweets.  However, I don't understand line by line what is happening; especially with the

```
Math.floor(Math.random() * arr.length)
```

My guess is that it picks a random array length, which is truncated to the lowest integer and then assigned as the array length of randArrayEl[].

However, I don't understand how it selects random first and last names with the following:

```
  return randArrayEl(fakeFirsts) + " " + randArrayEl(fakeLasts);
```

Here's the whole code.  Can anyone explain the logic of each line?

```
var randArrayEl = function(arr)
{
  return arr[Math.floor(Math.random() * arr.length)];
};

var getFakeName = function()
{
  var fakeFirsts = ['Nimit', 'Dave', 'Will', 'Charlotte', 'Jacob','Ethan','Sophia','Emma','Madison'];
  var fakeLasts = ["Alley", 'Stacky', 'Fullstackerson', 'Nerd', 'Ashby', 'Gatsby', 'Hazelnut', 'Cookie', 'Tilde', 'Dash'];
  return randArrayEl(fakeFirsts) + " " + randArrayEl(fakeLasts);
};

var getFakeTweet = function()
{
  var awesome_adj = ['awesome','breathtaking','amazing','sexy','sweet','cool','wonderful','mindblowing'];
  return "Fullstack Academy is " + randArrayEl(awesome_adj) + "! The instructors are just so " + randArrayEl(awesome_adj) + ". #fullstacklove #codedreams";
};

for(var i=0; i<10; i++)
{
  store.push(getFakeName(), getFakeTweet());
}
```

Also, what is the for loop at the end supposed to do?

Answer (score 2):

`randArrayEl` returns a random element from the array. It does this by picking a random integer between 0 and `arr.length-1` (because `Math.random()` never returns exactly 1), and returning that element from the array.

So `randArrayEl(fakeFirsts)` returns a random name from the `fakeFirsts` array, and likewise for `randArrayEl(fakeLasts)`. Concatenate them with a space and you have a random first and last name combo!

`getFakeTweet` works in a similar way with `randArrayEl(awesome_adj)` to describe Fullstack Academy.

Finally, the `for` loop puts 10 random tweets and associated random names in the `store` array.

Answer (score 0):

randArrayEl picks a single random item from the array.

Take a look at the line from inside towards outside:

- `Math.random()` gives you a random number between 0 and 1;
- `Math.random() * arr.length` gives you a random number from 0 to n,
  where n is the number of items in that array; but it's not a whole
  number/integer;
- `Math.floor(Math.random() * arr.length)` gives you a rounded integer
  number from 0 to n;
- `arr[Math.floor(Math.random() * arr.length)]` gives you the text that
  corresponds to that number.

The for loop at the end puts a fake name and a fake tweet into the "store" and repeats it 10 times.

Answer (score 0):

In the line

```
Math.floor(Math.random() * arr.length)
```

Math.random() returns a floating point number x in the range 0 <= x < 1. Multiplying that by arr.length gives you a floating point number in the range 0 <= x < arr.length. Taking math.Floor of that removes the fractional part, so you are left with an integer n in the range 0 <= n <= arr.length-1.

If you now access array[n], for some random n, you will get a random string from the array of strings. So the line

```
return randArrayEl(fakeFirsts) + " " + randArrayEl(fakeLasts);
```

returns a random first name from fakeFirsts concatenated with a random second name chosen from fakeLasts (separated by a space).